# Error #1241 SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting error code #1241. I have been looking to find an answer but I can't find an answer that helped me.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT name, address, city, phone  
FROM customer
WHERE customer.ID IN (
    SELECT customer.ID, COUNT(*) AS amount_reservations 
    FROM customer, (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM customer, reservations 
        WHERE rent_time = 'weekend' AND 
        ID = customer_ID
    ) AS foo 
    WHERE customer.ID = foo.ID 
    GROUP BY customer.ID 
    HAVING amount_reservations > 1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery `SELECT customer.ID, COUNT(*) AS amount_reservations` should have a SINGLE column, not two.

Change it as:

```
SELECT name, address, city, phone  
  FROM customer  
  WHERE customer.ID IN (
    SELECT customer.ID
      FROM customer, (
        SELECT ID FROM customer, reservations 
          WHERE rent_time = 'weekend' AND ID = customer_ID
        ) AS foo 
      WHERE customer.ID = foo.ID 
      GROUP BY customer.ID HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: You aren't defining `amount_reservations` - replace that with `count(*)` and this could work.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks it works now, but could you please explain why this is necessary?

Comment: In SQL the **IN** operator compares **tuples**. A tuple can have 1 or more values. Therefore, you can compare 1 value to 1 value, or two values to two values, etc.; however, you cannot compare 1 value to two values (your issue). You were trying to compare one value (customer.ID) against two values (customer.ID, count(*)). That's not accepted in SQL.

Comment: So you mean I can't compare the ID to the amount of reservations? I guess that makes sense. Thanks! Oh and btw your code worked without the suggestion of sgeddes. Should I still use that suggestion or just leave it as it is?

Comment: Yes, you can (even if it doesn't make sense). What you cannot do is to compare [123] against [456, 789]. This doesn't make sense. **ONE** number against **TWO** numbers? This is not valid in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend rewriting your query.  Remove the subqueries -- they aren't needed.  Then use `explicit joins` instead of commas.

```
select c.id, c.name, c.address, c.city, c.phone  
from customer c
    join reservations r on c.id = r.customer_id
where r.rent_time = 'weekend'
group by c.id, c.name, c.address, c.city, c.phone  
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This looks very advanced. I think haven't reached this level at school yet. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `in`, you can radically simplify the query:

```
SELECT c.name, c.address, c.city, c.phone  
FROM customer c
WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT r.customer_id
               FROM reservations r
               WHERE r.rent_time = 'weekend' 
               GROUP BY r.customer_id
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
              ) ;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases and qualified column names for all column references.
- You don't need a `JOIN` in the subquery, because you have the customer id in the reservations table.